# Slow loading of PHP script with HighChart

Tags: javascript, php, performance, highcharts, loading

I am facing an issue that is related to loading speed. I am calling a PHP function which returns a value of 400 milliseconds on average. But when I call the same function in a loop and inside a HighChart Data series, then the average loading time is greater than 5 seconds.

```
function CheckAQI($station, $date, $connection) {
        $stime = '00:00';
        $etime = '23:55';
        $sdate = $date. ' ' . $stime;
        $edate = $date. ' ' . $etime;
        $sql = "SELECT SUM(O3)/COUNT(O3) as o3_polluant FROM test_uploads WHERE dateandtime >= '$sdate' AND dateandtime <= '$edate' AND station_id = '$station'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $o3_polluant = $row['o3_polluant'];
        $data = pollute_data('O3', $o3_polluant, $con);
        $pl_lower = $data[0];
        $pl_upper = $data[1];
        $aqi_lower = $data[2];
        $aqi_upper = $data[3];
        $Idiff = $aqi_upper - $aqi_lower;
        $Bpdiff = $pl_upper - $pl_lower;
        $plDiff = $o3_polluant - $pl_lower;
        $f1 = $Idiff*$plDiff;
        $f2 = $f1/$Bpdiff;
        $aqi = $f2 + $aqi_lower;
        return $no2_polluant_aqi = floor($aqi * 100) / 100;
    }
```

```
    function pollute_data($pollutant, $pollutant_value, $connection{
        $pollutant_lower = strtolower($pollutant);
        $col1 = $pollutant_lower. '_lower';
        $col2 = $pollutant_lower. '_upper';
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM aqiindex WHERE $pollutant_value BETWEEN $col1 AND $col2";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
        $row3  = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
        $pl_lower = $row3[$col1];
        $pl_upper = $row3[$col2];
        $aqi_lower = $row3['aqi_lower'];
        $aqi_upper = $row3['aqi_upper'];
        return array($pl_lower,$pl_upper,$aqi_lower,$aqi_upper);
    }
```

```
<script src="highchart/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AQI Historic Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
            categories: [
                <?php 
                $my_date = $date;            
                $ip = 1;
                while($ip < 15){
                          $repeat = strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($my_date));
                          $my_date = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
                          $newDate = date("d,m,Y", strtotime($my_date));
                ?>
                [<?php echo $newDate; ?> ],
              <?php $ip++; } ?>
              ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'AQI Range'
                }
            },
             series: [{
                name: 'Township AQMS',
                data: [
                  <?php 
                    $my_date = $date; 
                    $i= 1;
                    while($i < 15){   
                      $repeat = strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($my_date));
                      $my_date = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
                      $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($my_date));
                      $newDate. ' (' .date('l', strtotime($newDate)). ')';
                      ?> 
                      ['1',  
                          <?php 
                            $GraphTownshipAQI = CheckAQI(1, $newDate, $con); 
                            if(is_nan($GraphMobileAQI)){echo 0;} else {echo $GraphMobileAQI;}
                          ?>],
                      <?php $i++; 
                    } 
                  ?>
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Townhall AQMS',
                data: [
                  <?php 
                    $my_date = $date; 
                    $i= 1;
                    while($i < 15){   
                          $repeat = strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($my_date));
                          $my_date = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
                          $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($my_date));
                          $newDate. ' (' .date('l', strtotime($newDate)). ')';
                        ?> 
                     ['0', 
                          <?php 
                            $GraphMobileAQI = CheckAQI(2, $newDate, $con); 
                            if(is_nan($GraphMobileAQI)){echo 0;} else {echo $GraphMobileAQI;}
                          ?>],
                      <?php $i++; 
                    } 
                  ?>
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Mobile AQMS',
                data: [
                  <?php 
                    $my_date = $date; 
                    $i= 1;
                    while($i < 15){   
                          $repeat = strtotime("-1 day",strtotime($my_date));
                          $my_date = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
                          $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($my_date));
                          $newDate. ' (' .date('l', strtotime($newDate)). ')';
                        ?> 
                      ['1', 
                          <?php 
                            $GraphMobileAQI = CheckAQI(3, $newDate, $con);
                            if(is_nan($GraphMobileAQI)){echo 0;} else {echo $GraphMobileAQI;}
                          ?>],
                      <?php $i++; 
                    } 
                  ?>
                ],
            }],
        });
    });

</script>
```

When I call the CheckAQI function individually, the loading is 400 milliseconds. But the high Chart loading time is 5 seconds.

NOTE: I am calculating only one pollutant(O3) in the CheckAQI function. I have to calculate 6 pollutants in the future.

Looking forward to the solution of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Hafiz Ejaz

Comment: ignore the return value of the CheckAQI function. It should be $o3_polluant.

Comment: Hi,  Could you share the code in JavaScript and give an example of the data you get from PHP?

Comment: Sorry, @SebastianHajdus I could not get it. Do you want me to share the output? The script output is a high chart. there is no option to upload screenshots here.

Comment: To see what's going on you need to recreate your chart in an online JavaScript editor, are you able to do that?